# Phantom Columns: Entity Framework migration

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

While in the process of updating the database structure on my current project, I added a dependency to a link table, such that the relationship is:

```
JobOffer -< JobApplication >- StaffMember
```

When adding this change as a new migration, several other fields were "added" to the migration `Up()` and `Down()` methods. I no longer have the exact fields, but they were along the lines of `Skills.JobOffer_ID`. The reason *added* is in quotations is because I never ran `update-database`, instead I removed these unnecessary fields and then ran `update-database`.

The update seemed to work and the correct fields were added, but on running the code I get this error:
[image: SQL Exception referencing non-existant columns]

The columns are not in the database, but I don't know why they are being referenced in the first place, they were never created and never explicitly written in any code.

**How do I prevent these errors that are referencing non-existant columns?**

**EDIT:**

The current model is below, the only change from the last model is the addition of OwnerID to JobOpportunity.

[image: Database Logical model]

The current migration is as follows (minus the fields I deleted, working on figuring out what they were)

```
public partial class JobChanges : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Name", c => c.String());
        AddColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID", "dbo.Staff", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID", "dbo.Staff");
        DropIndex("dbo.JobOpportunities", new[] { "OwnerID" });
        DropColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID");
        DropColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Name");
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Just realised only JobOpportunities, Staff, and Skills exist in the database atm #facepalm#

**Edit 3:**

Rescaffolded the faulty migration, this is what I started with:

```
public partial class JobChanges : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Name", c => c.String());
        AddColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Staff_ID", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Skills", "Staff_ID", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID1", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Staff", "JobOpportunity_ID", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Staff_ID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Staff", "JobOpportunity_ID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Skills", "Staff_ID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID1");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Staff_ID", "dbo.Staff", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Skills", "Staff_ID", "dbo.Staff", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Staff", "JobOpportunity_ID", "dbo.JobOpportunities", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID", "dbo.JobOpportunities", "ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID", "dbo.Staff", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID1", "dbo.JobOpportunities", "ID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID1", "dbo.JobOpportunities");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID", "dbo.Staff");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID", "dbo.JobOpportunities");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Staff", "JobOpportunity_ID", "dbo.JobOpportunities");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Skills", "Staff_ID", "dbo.Staff");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Staff_ID", "dbo.Staff");
        DropIndex("dbo.Skills", new[] { "JobOpportunity_ID1" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Skills", new[] { "JobOpportunity_ID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Skills", new[] { "Staff_ID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Staff", new[] { "JobOpportunity_ID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.JobOpportunities", new[] { "Staff_ID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.JobOpportunities", new[] { "OwnerID" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Staff", "JobOpportunity_ID");
        DropColumn("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID1");
        DropColumn("dbo.Skills", "JobOpportunity_ID");
        DropColumn("dbo.Skills", "Staff_ID");
        DropColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Staff_ID");
        DropColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "OwnerID");
        DropColumn("dbo.JobOpportunities", "Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: these "unnecessary fields" are the FK columns in the database.

Comment: Yeah, but they were in tables not related to the tables I wanted

Comment: Well, strictly they are related, but not for the purposes of the new fields I added

Comment: *"instead I removed these unnecessary fields"* You shouldn't do that. Having such fields in the migration is clear indication that something in your entity model is wrong. Please post the relevant model (and configuration if any). It's not possible to help w/o that.

Comment: I'm going to take a copy of the database, rollback the changes and add the link tables, see if that helps

Comment: what is the mapping for the context?